# iOS Sending a Push Notification From an iOS App, APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there anything preventing SENDING a push notification FROM an iOS application? There are reasons for my madness. If so, are there any good examples out there? I have code that should be working and if there is no blocking reason, I will post the code.

I tried on Verizon and AT&T. Would want it over a carrier for now.

Please do not comment on why, etc.

[addition]

This would not be for a public app, testing internal only.

Comment: Nothing like -2 off the bat with no explanation.....

Comment: "I have code that should be working and if there is no blocking reason, I will post the code." might explain it. Questions like these don't get answered without code.

Comment: It is quite a bit of code and just wanted to ask the question first before positing the code.  If the service providers are not blocking the send push port, then I might post the code.  I am using Urban  Airship for now.  If I need to go native will post the code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason what this wouldn't work. You'll have to include the push certificate with your application, and your users will have to download a new version of your app every time the certificate expires (which means once a year). You'll also need to send to each device all the device tokens of devices it should send notifications to.

The sending code should be the same as it would be in a server that sends push notifications, but you would have to implement it in objective C.

All in all it doesn't seem like a good idea, since you'll need a server anyway (for each device to get the device tokens of other devices), so it makes more sense that the server will do the sending.

Comment: I like your answer better than mine :) only thing missing is: many short SSL connections from many (thousands) different IP-s would most probably lead to Apple revoking his APNS certificates.

Comment: @rokjarc You have a good point, if the OP intends to send many notifications from the app, he/she may be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes - there are a few things that prevent you from sending push notification from iOS.

Even if you manage to install (use in your app) certificates needed  to properly connect to Apple's APNS server their policy is to start blocking clients that create many short connections.

So for public app you would need to use a "normal" way of setting up your PHP server that manages communication with APNS. Otherwise many public IP's (devices) using your credentials would lead to blocking your app APNS certificate.

If this would be just for private use then there is no reason not to give it a try.